# NuGet Restore can't find Microsoft.Build.dll

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to get my Azure Devops Pipeline up and running, but when running nuget restore, it fails saying: Could not load file or assembly 'xxxxxxxxx\Microsoft.Build.dll'.
I've used multiple NuGet Versions but it just wont work the way it should.
I have also read there could be some problems using different versions of NuGet and MSBuild which don't work together, but I'm running out of options and motivation.
The dll he is asking for doesn't exist, but it should have been installed with VisualStudio.

I've tried multiple NuGetVersions but it's still the same.
Except for sometimes when he tells me he can't find the .sln altogether which is another step back compared to where I am struggeling now.

Comment: If you'd like help, please provide **details**. For example, your pipeline's YAML. And the version of .NET you're using. And precise error messages and log files.

Comment: If you are using a NuGet restore task to restore packages defined in your `.sln` `packages.config` or `.proj` file, can you edit the post to contain a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Please share the [pipeline definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/migrate/from-classic-pipelines?view=azure-devops#export-your-classic-pipeline) and [debug logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops) of the affected pipeline in the post.

Comment: Edit: after a longer trial and error period I managed to get it up and running